# I want to create a dict like this from input in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, graph

all the contents must be inserted from the input

```
graph={
'A':{'B':3,'C':4},
'B':{'A':3,'C':5},
'C':{'B':5,'D':'1'},
'D':{'C':1},
}
```

Comment: User insert A and then insert B:5  , C:4 and so on...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
def make_dict():
    d = {}
    while True:
        key = input("Enter the key of dict or stay blank to finish adding key to this level of dict: ")
        if key == "":  # just stay blank to out from func
            break
        ch = input(f"Do you wanna to create nested dict for the key{key}? [y / <Press Enter for No>] ")
        if ch == "y":
            value = make_dict()  # use recursion
        else:
            value = input(f"Enter the value for the key {key}: ")
        d[key] = value
    return d


print(make_dict())
```

[link to screenshot](https://sun1-29.userapi.com/s/v1/if2/ExIPPPQ-bxF5O1xeLk8mNAzlTWw5h2nMXTTdC07Aa_hHZCi9cjaJRT9Cfn-FBPrUhzDUQLWW7Mh6TFZtS7GwiMQy.jpg?size=2020x740&quality=95&type=album)

Comment: Enter the key of dict: A
Do you wanna to create nested dict for the key : A? [y / <Press Enter for No>]y
Enter the key of dict: B
Do you wanna to create nested dict for the key : B? [y / <Press Enter for No>]y
Enter the key of dict: C
Do you wanna to create nested dict for the key : C? [y / <Press Enter for No>]
Enter the value for the key C: 3
this is the output : {'A': {'B': {'C': '3'}}}  and its not true , but thanks for answering

Comment: output is : {'A': {'B': {'C': '3'}}} but it must be {'A':{'B': (A number) ,'C' : 3}

Comment: @nooblearner please describe your answer in the post itself, not the comments. Also, the code has comments with a leading `//` instead of `#`.

Comment: @nooblearner I think you just not correctly understand how it works) I edited my code in a part of screen messages. My solution supports as much levels of nesting as you want. For creation your example  {'A':{'B':3,'C':4}} you need this way of screen entering: A -> y -> B -> Enter -> 3 -> C -> Enter -> 4 -> Enter -> Enter. Try it out!)

Comment: I do as you say.  But the output was : { 'A' : { 'B' : '3' }.  (Thanks for your help) I really need to solve this code please help

Comment: @nooblearner I think you do something wrong due to entering values. Check it again: A -> y -> B -> Enter -> 3 -> C -> Enter -> 4 -> Enter -> Enter. Look at my screenshot which I added to my answer above (link to screenshot)

Comment: Bro thanks a lot, you were right, I change my IDE and try your code. the problem was my IDE.your code is exactly right. Thanks, thanks thanks...

Comment: @nooblearner my pleasure)

Answer (score 0):

Take the input in JSON format and then you can easily use `json.loads` to convert it to a dictionary.

```
>>> import json
>>> graph = json.loads(input("Enter graph as JSON: "))
Enter graph as JSON: {"A":{"B":3,"C":4},"B":{"A":3,"C":5},"C":{"B":5,"D":"1"},"D":{"C":1}}
>>> import pprint
>>> pprint.pprint(graph)
{'A': {'B': 3, 'C': 4},
 'B': {'A': 3, 'C': 5},
 'C': {'B': 5, 'D': '1'},
 'D': {'C': 1}}
```

Comment: I can not use JSON bro

Comment: Why on earth not?  You didn’t include any specifications on input format in your question, so it seems safe to assume the format can be anything you want.  Just use one that makes your life easy.

Comment: you are right but for the answer, I can't use JSON, thanks for the answer

Comment: You really can, just do `import json`.  There’s no reason for it not to work, it’s included with Python.

Comment: bro this is homework, i should solve it without JSON

Comment: Tell your teacher that in real life people just use JSON.  That’s a better lesson for you to be learning than anything you’d learn by handing in code you got from SO (which is zero).  Explain it like that and they’ll give you an A for Academic Honesty, bro.

Answer (score 0):

```
record_to_insert = int(input("num of record to insert :: "))

dic = {}
for i in range(record_to_insert):

   print("")
   key_name = input("parent key name :: ")
   dic[key_name] = {}

   print("Enter how many number of key,value pairs you want for key :: ", 
   key_name)
   num_of_child_keyvalues_to_insert = int(input(""))

   for k in range(num_of_child_keyvalues_to_insert):

      key = input("child key name :: ")
      value = input("Value name :: ")
      dic[key_name][key] = value


print(dic)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).